# Changing alpha of object using script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy and I want it to have a blinking effect (when it gets hit) by changing the alpha.

I'm not doing this using animation due to some other animation already being there. So, I'm changing the alpha of the sprite using a script, but it's not working.

Here's the script:

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
 {
     if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
     {
         StartCoroutine("Blinker");
     }
 }

 IEnumerator Blinker()
 {
     GameObject This = this.gameObject;

     Color tmp = This.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;
     Color tmp2 = This.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color;

     tmp.a = 0f;
     tmp2.a = 1;
     This.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = tmp;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
     This.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = tmp2;
 }
```

Here's the inspector of the object I'm changing:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the inspector properties for the sprite you're changing?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Do the code execute and the effect is not the expected, or it doesn't reach the coroutine?

Comment: I've added Debug logs and every function is called. The code is meant to fade out the sprite for the duration of the variable 'sec' and then become normal again to give it a blinking look when the player is hit with a bullet. It doesn't happen. There's no blinking even though the courotine is called. It's as if the code changing the alpha doesn't work.

Comment: @Draco18s I've added a screenshot

Comment: @VivekNegi Do you change `sprite color` in animations that you have for this game object?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi No the animations are just for moving the object up and down

Comment: I copy pasted your code into my project and it works fine.  I know you have already assured us that the animator is not affecting the color, but please try disabling the `Animator` component anyways and see if the blinking effect works.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time @AlexMyers. I'll try disabling it now.

Comment: @AlexMyers It's working when you disable the animator. But the animation only changes the position. How should I make it work then?

Comment: Make sure for every animation in your animator that none of them modify the Color property for even a single frame.

Comment: My first guess was that the sprite shader being used didn't support an alpha (that sort of issue is pretty common), but didn't get around to checking it. Good job on Alex checking the animator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy pasted your code into my project and verified it works as written.  The problem must be related to a conflict with one of your animations.

Go through every animation in your enemy animator and ensure `SpriteRenderer.color` is not present in any of them.

Comment: Yes! There was an animation that I wasn't using but was attached to the animator that used color. Thank you so much for this!